# Installing higher version of R in PHP-Apache image/container?

Tags: r, docker, dockerfile

I am developing a docker container with php-apache image. This container should contain a higher version of R (4.2.0 for example) to activate native pipe operator `|>`. However I met an error saying `E: Version '4.2.0' for 'r-base' was not found` when I build the container, nor it can be found via `apt policy r-base` (it ends up with Candidate: 4.0.4-1).

Here's my `Dockerfile`

```
  FROM php:8.1.1-apache
  RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
  RUN apt-get update && \
      apt-get install -y \
    nodejs \
        r-base

... other cmds ...
```

Since I have a external `docker-compose` file to config the network thing, it's less likely that I will trun to `r-base` image. Can I ask if there's a way to install higher version of base R inside the container?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What distro and version of linux is used for `php:8.1.1-apache`? For instance, if you're using Ubuntu, you can use one of R-Project's [PPAs](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) for installing the up-to-date versions.

Comment: After that, for speed, you may want to use https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/ or similar

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. `php:8.1.1-apache` uses Debian 11 bullseye (info from `/etc/os-release` inside the docker). So I've put

``` 
RUN echo 'deb http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian bullseye-cran40/' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

But it doesn't help..

Comment: (Sorry if it's an obvious thing, I don't know enough about you or the rest of the `Dockerfile` to know for sure.) Did you `apt-get update` after the `echo` statement? Said differently, looking at http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/bullseye-cran40/ I can see that `r-base_4.3.2...` is indeed there, so if you `RUN echo '..' >> /etc/apt/sources.list` and then run `apt-get update`, you should then be able to install `r-base_4.3.2...`.

Comment: Yeah I did `apt-get update` after `echo`. And then I met "signature validation -- NO_PUBKEY" error. Then I put ` RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.debian.org PUBKEY_HERE` in between `echo` and `apt-get` I got another error saying `gnupg, gnupg2 and gnupg1 do not seem to be installed` error. Seems I am making thing more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're hitting some but not all of the wickets to be able to get the newest `r-base_4.3.2...`.

The required steps: install `gnupg`; add to `sources.list`; import the new-repo key; then update apt and install. Generally this means you'll need to update first, then install gnupg, then do the sources/key, then update again.

Something like the following (untested!):

```
  FROM php:8.1.1-apache
  RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
  RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg && \
    echo 'deb cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian bullseye-cran40/' >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    gpg --armor --export '95C0FAF38DB3CCAD0C080A7BDC78B2DDEABC47B7' | \
      tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/cran_debian_key.asc && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
      nodejs r-base
...
```

Most docker images do not pre-fill the `apt` list of packages, so I believe there is no way here to avoid the double `apt-get update` process (I may be wrong). If by chance `apt-get install -y gnupg` works before an `apt-get update`, then you can reduce it by one, but I find that unlikely for a few reasons.

Comment: Okay I finally got R 4.2.0 installed by just switching the image over to php:8.2-apache and simply run `apt-get update` and `apt-get install -y r-base`. Since I need to push my project, that could be the end so far. But I'll still give a try for your config soon because my colleagues are sticking on `php:8.1.1-apache`. Will do the test and let you know if that works! Thank you so much:)